# iOS: Get current atmospheric pressure from iPhone 6 with M8 chip

Tags: ios, pressure

As I understand the official Apple documentation it's only possible to get the relative altitude change out of the new M8 chip which is in every new iPhone 6 and 6 plus.

What I need is the current atomspheric pressure (absolute value is fine, I do not need a relative value based on sea level). there is an app in the store which exatly does this, but I've no clue how to get this data out of my iPhone 6.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/barometer++/id922220265?mt=8

Could you point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a quick look at the documentation, and in `CMAltitudeData` there's a `pressure` method that returns the current atmospheric pressure in kilopascals: [CMAltitudeData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAltitudeData_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMAltitudeData/pressure) for the reference, it's just at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you, don't know why I missed this data field in the documentation.

Comment: To be fair, searching for atmospheric pressure returned nothing in the documentation, I think I just got lucky and looked at the right thing.